# How Elasticsearch query template is rendered

Tags: templates, elasticsearch

Is there a way to see how my Elasticsearch query is rendered? Not the results, but the query itself. I'm having some problems and I would like to debug, but I don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `GET /_validate/query?rewrite=true`

reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html

Comment: this will provide the lucene query that will be executed

Comment: but it doesn't, even in the documentation at most it explains the error

Comment: "When the query is valid, the explanation defaults to the string representation of that query. With rewrite set to true, the explanation is more detailed showing the actual Lucene query that will be executed."

Comment: Yes, thank you. But that is the problem - I need to debug, so my query is not valid :)

Comment: Maybe you could post your query in a separate question and people can help you figure out the problem. :)